# Locale app/Resource/view/base.html.php Symfony2

Tags: symfony, locale

How can I translate my `base.html.php` layout?

```html
<!-- app/Resources/views/base.html.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $view['translator']->trans('Bye'); ?>
        <div id="content">
            <?php $view['slots']->output('body') ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```xml
<!-- app/Resources/translations/messages.de.xliff -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Bye</source>
                <target>Auf Wiedersehen.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

I do have also for my bundle `src/../Bundle/../translation/messages.de.xliff`. This works properly. It starts with `id="1"`.

So how can I get the translation to work in base.html.php?

Is it possible to change also pics with different locale in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything you want as a target string, so urls can be possible:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>foo_image</source>
                <target>images/foo.de.png</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

```php
<img src="<?= $view['translator']->trans('foo_image') ?>">
```

Comment: Yes you are right with email. Pretty easy. But my first question is not solved. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Symfony just didn't cleared the cache as well as it should be. Thanks again!