# Translation catalog generation with Symfony2 for main app

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I used the following command to generate the catalogs of my different Bundles and it worked well.

```
php app/console translation:update --dump-messages --force fr ProjectBlogBundle
```

But how should I do to translate the view that we can find on /app/Resources/views/* ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [command code](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Command/TranslationUpdateCommand.php#L38), it looks like it's not possible: the bundle name is required and must be provided.

However, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059362/locale-app-resource-view-base-html-php-symfony2) out.

Even though you can't automatically extract/update translation segments from those views, the runtime translation should work, provided that you use the same translation domain.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is rather dated, I figured I might add this just for anybody else stumbling across this:

It seems that the desired functionality has been added in the meantime (Symfony 2.8+).

If you run the command like this:

```
$ app/console translation:update --help
Usage:
  translation:update [options] [--] <locale> [<bundle>]

Arguments:
  locale                               The locale
  bundle                               The bundle name or directory where to load the messages, defaults to app/Resources folder
```

It seems the bundle name has become optionale and the command will default to `app/Resources`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the @Jan's answer helped me. So there is an example.

```
cd app/
php ./console console translation:update --dump-messages --force fr .
```

As . is a directory (the current directory), the translator will try to load the subdirectory /Resources, so here it will try to load app/Resources/.